# How do I find hostname in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I recently opened a database instance on AWS using RDS. I can't find the IP or hostname to the database. Can somebody help? I'm using MariaDB version 10.5.13. If anymore info is needed, just tell me. I'm new to this so I'm not exactly sure whats needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no specific IP adress shown to user in AWS Console, but you can find the hostname and FQDN of the DB under `connectivity and security` tab of the RDS Database listed as "endpoint".

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Comment: and the hostname is the endpoint, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: so this should work? https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/849715509079703572/942400428044353536/unknown.png

Comment: Yes, this should work, but it's also related with the network configuration, If your RDS database is in the private network and public access disabled, you can't access it from outside of your VPC, and also there is a security group situation. your IP or IP block blocks that you wanna connect to RDS (in this case your discord server I assume) should be allowed in RDS security group. If you having trouble with connecting. There are these considerations too, but hostname is what I mentioned in the post.